# Why does Gerrit review return a "not a valid patch set" error?

Tags: gerrit

I am referring to this [document](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-review.html) in order to post ratings to Gerrit server.

However, i face some error while running the following command:

```
 ssh -p <port> <gerrit host> gerrit review Ibaabcd10fcf35182f592806c67077a2e72d72727,51 --message 'Build Successful' --code-review +1
```

Error:

```
fatal: "Ibaabcd10fcf35182f592806c67077a2e72d72727,51" is not a valid patch set
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two issues:

1) The [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-review.html) is wrong, the correct is ***CHANGENUMBER,PATCHSET*** instead of ***CHANGEID,PATCHSET***.

2) You need to add double quotes to the --message parameter

So your command will work with something like the following (change the CHANGENUMBER accordingly):

```
ssh -p <port> <gerrit host> gerrit review 50147,51 --message '"Build Successful"' --code-review +1
```

Comment: thanks for the correction. the documentation maybe is outdated and need to be updated. it is working as per expected! thank you~